# Escape Tilde in Powershell Replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working on a powershell script to parse a file into a different delimited format that can easily be loaded into Excel or a DB.

I've gotten it mostly figured except for finding and replacing the string "~S~|" where all characters should be taken literal.

I've tried the following to no avail:
"\~S\~\|"
"~S~\|"
"~S~|"   <-- this one is squirrely since | is or in RegEx land

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The only meta character of that selection would be `|`. The following regex will match that exact sequence: `~S~\|`

Comment: This works fine in the console but through script with a really long string with multiple instances it skipped some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around this with a work around. Thank you for all your input, all answers work as you described.

In order for me to get this to work in a very long string with multiple instances of the 'find' value I ended up having to build the string as it grew.

For example:

```
$tString = $_
$tString = $tString -replace 'Name:', ''
$tString = $tString -replace 'Id:', ''
$tString = $tString -replace 'Administrative group:', ''
$tString = $tString -replace 'Administrative class\(es\):', ''
$tString = $tString -replace 'Primary group:', ''
$tString = $tString -replace 'Session group:', ''
$tString = $tString -replace '~S~([^-]+)\|', '$1|'
$tString = $tString -replace ';\|', ';'
return $tString
```

Answer (score 6):

The regex.escape method is designed for this kind of situations where you don't know which characters are considered special (meta characters).

```
PS> [regex]::escape("~S~|")
~S~\|
```

You can see that the only meta character is the pipe sign (e.g '|') and that the escape method escaped it for you (added a backslash in front of it).

```
PS> "this~S~|is~S~|a~S~|dog" -replace [regex]::escape('~S~|')
thisisadog
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try this :

```
$string = "this~S~|is~S~|a~S~|dog"
$string -replace '~S~\|',' '
```